# Reference for the Security Analysis of Ring-LWE

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, reference-request, ring-lwe

Can someone please share a link of any research paper or web-page analyzing the security of Ring-LWE? Essentially, how should I choose my parameters to get security equivalent to 128-bit or 256-bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should visit the [Homomorphic Encryption Standardization](http://homomorphicencryption.org) web page. There you can find [Homomorphic Encryption Standardization](http://homomorphicencryption.org/standard/).

Also, there is a workshop [The Second Homomorphic Encryption Standardization Workshop](https://projects.csail.mit.edu/HEWorkshop/) there you can find this document

- [Homomorphic Encryption Standard](https://projects.csail.mit.edu/HEWorkshop/HomomorphicEncryptionStandard2018.pdf) see section 2.0.3

I hope, all this will help in your research.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the references - it definitely helps!