# How to set parameters (i.e., gen, ords and mvec) for bootstrapping in HElib?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I'm using the homomorphic encryption library, HElib, to do experiments.
I tried to use bootstrapping with parameters that are not in the table provided with HElib.
But I have no idea how to choose the parameters (i.e, gen, ords and mvec) for bootstrapping.

Below is an example in HElib (`examples/BGV_binary_arithmetic.cpp`)

```
  // Plaintext prime modulus.
  long p = 2;
  // Cyclotomic polynomial - defines phi(m).
  long m = 4095;
  // Hensel lifting (default = 1).
  long r = 1;
  // Number of bits of the modulus chain.
  long bits = 500;
  // Number of columns of Key-Switching matrix (typically 2 or 3).
  long c = 2;
  // Factorisation of m required for bootstrapping.
  std::vector<long> mvec = {7, 5, 9, 13};
  // Generating set of Zm* group.
  std::vector<long> gens = {2341, 3277, 911};
  // Orders of the previous generators.
  std::vector<long> ords = {6, 4, 6};
```

**My question:** In my experiment, I need the ciphertext with the exact number of slots (such as `slots= 256, 1024, 4096`). Thus, I have to find the proper `m, p, bits` to generate such a ciphertext with these slots. But for these `m, p, bits`, I don't know how to set `mvec, gens, ords`.

Here is a particular example:

```
    long m = 12800;
    long p = 127;
    long r = 1;
    long bits = 119;
    long c = 2;
    vector<long> mvec = {25, 512};
    vector<long> gens = {2, 128};
    vector<long> ords = {43, 4351};
```

Throw an exception: `terminating with uncaught exception of type helib::LogicError: Bad user-supplied generator`

```
// Some Information about this context:
m = 12800, p = 127, phi(m) = 5120
  ord(p) = 20
  normBnd = 1.23107
  polyNormBnd = 1.23107
  factors = [2 5]
  generator 43 has order (== Z_m^*) of 128
  generator 4351 has order (== Z_m^*) of 2
r = 1
nslots = 256
hwt = 0
ctxtPrimes = [6,7]
specialPrimes = [8]
number of bits = 173

security level = 98.4643
```

**Update:** I run an example with the parameters found by HElib (`misc/psi/params.cpp`), but throw an exception `LogicError: rawModSwitch scaled noise exceeds bound: 309684.692524`.

The given parameters are: `phim=7056, d=28, m=12789, m=(3^2)*7^2*{29}, m/phim(m)=1.81, C=74 D=2 E=2, mvec="[49 261]" gens="[11224 7106]" ords="[42 6]"`

The code is written for performing multiple multiplications while checking the noise and performing bootstrapping.

```
    long m = 12789;
    long p = 127;
    long r = 1;
    long bits = 119;
    long c = 2;
    // Factorisation of m required for bootstrapping.
    vector<long> mvec = {49, 261};
    // Generating set of Zm* group.
    vector<long> gens = {11224, 7106};
    // Orders of the previous generators.
    vector<long> ords = {42, 6};
    
    Context context = ContextBuilder<BGV>()
                                   .m(m)
                                   .p(p)
                                   .r(r)
                                   .gens(gens)
                                   .ords(ords)
                                   .bits(bits)
                                   .c(c)
                                   .bootstrappable(true)
                                   .mvec(mvec)
                                   .build();
    // Key management
    SecKey secret_key(context);
    secret_key.GenSecKey();
    addSome1DMatrices(secret_key);
    addFrbMatrices(secret_key);
    secret_key.genRecryptData();
    const PubKey& public_key = secret_key;
    const EncryptedArray& ea = context.getEA();

    // create a ciphertext
    std::vector<long> ptxt(nslots);
    for (int i = 0; i < nslots; ++i) {
        ptxt[i] = 2;
    }
    Ctxt ctxt(public_key);
    ea.encrypt(ctxt, public_key, ptxt);

    // multiplication and bootstrapping
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (ctxt.bitCapacity() <= 50)
        {
            cout << "Begin bootstrapping!" << endl;
            public_key.thinReCrypt(ctxt);
        }
        ctxt.square();
    }
```

The exception:

```
Begin bootstrapping!
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type helib::LogicError: rawModSwitch scaled noise exceeds bound: 309684.692524
terminating with uncaught exception of type helib::LogicError: rawModSwitch scaled noise exceeds bound: 309684.692524
```

Comment: I think that Helib can choose the generators and orders for you if you don't pass them to the context.

Comment: [Homomorphic Encryption Standardization](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/74939/18298)

Comment: @HilderVitorLimaPereira Hi, Hilder. I have tried to create the context without passing the generators and orders to it, but it failed due to `LogicError: Cyclotomic polynomial mismatch`. Then I run the example given by HElib without passing them to the context, it doesn't work for the same reason. So it seems HElib does not support this.

Comment: @kelalaka Many thanks for your sharing!

Comment: I have already used the following code and it worked. Helib found the generators by itself. However, it is not using bootstrapping, so maybe that is the catch. You could test...

`helib::Context context = helib::ContextBuilder<helib::BGV>().m(16384).p(257).r(1).bits(250).c(3).skHwt(0).build();`

Comment: @HilderVitorLimaPereira, you're right, I used the above code and checked the generated `gens` and `ords` using the provided functions `context.getZMStar().ZmStarGen()` and `context.getZMStar().OrderOf()`.  However, I failed to run the code due to `rawModSwitch scaled noise exceeds bound` when I use the params `m = 8471, p=127, bits=200, r=1, c=2, gens = {3744, 2366}, ords = {42, -2}, mvec = {43, 197}` (security level is around `80`). But it's ok for the provided params in `benchmarks/bgv_fatboot.cpp`, although the security level is `0`.